# Symfony 4 - login page always redirects to itself

Tags: php, symfony4

I was trying to restrict access to the / path for the ROLE_USER, but when it redirects once to the login page, it keeps doing it and I get this :
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Here's my security.yaml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt


    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
            form_login: true
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

    role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Here's my SecurityController :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this to security.yml :

```
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```